# pure-ftpd not visible in yast FTP service

Tags: unix, ftp, suse, sles, pureftpd

I am using SLES 12, and under the

> yast-> Network Services-> FTP Server-> Selected Service

I have two options:

`(x)vsftpd
( )pure-ftpd`

Both are not editable, so I have installed pure-ftpd from sources. But even installation of pure-ftpd I am unable to change the setting above.

Answer (score 1):

SLES 12 just contains vsftpd. The pure-ftpd package is not delivered/supported, so the radio buttons are inactive and vsftpd is pre-selected.

You could add the Network repository for SLES 12 from the openSUSE Build service (see http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network/SLE_12/). After installing the pure-ftpd RPM from that repository manually, the YaST2 FTP module should ask you at startup which FTP daemon to use.